# Importing HBC library

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to import the following library: https://github.com/twitter/hbc

Which says I must import the folllowing in my pom.xml file:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbc-core</artifactId> <!-- or hbc-twitter4j -->
      <version>2.2.0</version> <!-- or whatever the latest version is -->
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I'm totally new to Maven. I'm using Eclipse, which already had Maven installed. I created a new Maven project, and then created a new .xml file named pom.xml with the above. However, nothing seems to have been imported; library stuff isn't working in the project. For example, the option to import "httpHosts" does not exist.

How am I meant to actually import this?

Comment: Please show your full pom file...

Comment: Unless that is your full pom file, in which case you'll be spending some time learning to use maven.

Comment: That's my full .pom file. Is there some tool for Eclipse I should be using instead?

Comment: You are missing few things here. Please, read: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Answer (score 0):

As Jorge Campos, suggests you need to do some reading on basic Maven. principles. So please read [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) in order to get started.

In order to help you a bit this is how your pom.xml should look like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
     <artifactId>hbc-core</artifactId> 
     <version>2.2.0</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

You need to take care the groupid and artifact id sections, but I hope you will find out, if you spend some time and read about Maven :)